# Android: Passing messages from Class to Fragment

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments, fragment

I have had a similar question to this not long ago but it wasn't written very well and have also changed my structure.

I am sending messages to a class when buttons are clicked in a fragment. The class in question is MessageInterface (not actually an interface).

I now want to send this message off to another fragment, and update some text in there. Here is what I have done so far.

This is the MessageInterface class, it successfully receives the message as I proved it with a log.

```
   public class MessageInterface {

    private String message;
    private static MessageInterface instance = new MessageInterface();
    private Message msg =  new Message();
    private Handler handler;
    private Bundle bundle;

    public MessageInterface() {

    }

    public static MessageInterface getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void sendData(final String str) {
        bundle = new Bundle();
        handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                message = str;
                if (!message.isEmpty()){
                    Log.i("Interface", "Message Revieved in Interface");
                    bundle.putString("Message", message );
                    msg.setData(bundle);
                    handler.sendMessage(msg);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public String getData() {
        return message;
    };

}
```

And this is the code in the receiving fragment:

```
private MessageInterface messageInterface = MessageInterface.getInstance();
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    statusText = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.statusText);

    handler2 = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
            statusText.setText((bundle.getString("Message")));
            Log.i("Status", "Message Revieved in Status Fragment");
        }
    };
}
```

Nothing gets logged here. The message is not being sent over.

If anyone could give me some tips on how to get this working then great. I also feel like this isn't the best way to to do it was i might end up with loads of data being sent through here.

How could I improve it if i can.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally i dont like that approach, Id suggest using `BroadcastReciever`s or `EventBus` to communicate between parts of your android app

For more details see [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html) and [this](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Comment: EventBus looks interesting. I will check it out. Thanks

Comment: Hi I got this error : Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.  I create a new EventBus event in a class that is working on its own thread. How can I access the message on the UI thread.

Comment: read this regarding your comments http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/delivery-threads-threadmode/